# How do I find the number of xpaths of Type A that are between two xpaths of Type B?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I’m trying to pull information from an online hockey game summary about penalties assessed during the game.

The penalties each have xpath:

```
[…]/div/div[x]/h4
```

where x is the number of the penalty

Inbetween, there are labels for the period the penalties occurred in, which have xpath:

```
[…]/div/h3[y]
```

where y is the number of the period.

The problem is, the start of a new period doesn’t reset the penalty number, and the summary looks like:

```
First period ([…]/div/h3[1])  
Penalty1 ([…]/div/div[1]/h4)  
Penalty2 ([…]/div/div[2]/h4)  
Second period ([…]/div/h3[2])  
Penalty3 ([…]/div/div[3]/h4)  
Penalty4 ([…]/div/div[4]/h4)  
Penalty5 ([…]/div/div[5]/h4)  
Third period ([…]/div/h3[3])  
Penalty6 ([…]/div/div[6]/h4)
```

And obviously, different games have different penalty numbers.

Is there a way I can find how many penalties were assessed in each period of a given game?
In the example above, I would want to know that there were 2 penalties in the first period, 3 in the second, and 1 in the third.

There are CSS selectors I could use in theory, but I'm not sure how I could use them:
Every penalty has CSS selector

```
div class=“boxscore-event-ctn"
```

and every period has CSS selector

```
h3 class=“margT40"
```

However, those same CSS selectors are also used for other elements in the HTML code.

Thank you!!

EDIT: Here's the relevant section of the HTML for a sample game.
This game had no penalties in the first period, 3 in the second, and 2 in the third:

```
      <div id="tabcontent102">
        <div class="pad40" style="background-image:none;">
          <h2>Penalties summary</h2>
          <h3 class="margT40">First Period</h3><span>No penalty</span>  
          <h3 class="margT40">Second period</h3>
          <div class="boxscore-event-ctn"><img style="width:40px;height:40px;float:left;"src="https://cdn.wssmedias.com/websimhockey/logos/LHSVL/Toronto.jpg">. 
            <h4>15:26 T. BERTUZZI (Rudesse)</h4>
            <div class="flowfix"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="boxscore-event-ctn"><img style="width:40px;height:40px;float:left;"src="https://cdn.wssmedias.com/websimhockey/logos/LHSVL/Toronto.jpg">. 
            <h4>09:40 M. CARLE (Avoir retenu)</h4>
            <div class="flowfix"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="boxscore-event-ctn"><img style="width:40px;height:40px;float:left;"src="https://cdn.wssmedias.com/websimhockey/logos/LHSVL/SanDiego.jpg">. 
            <h4>05:58 J. JOHNSON (Faire trébucher)</h4>
            <div class="flowfix"></div>
          </div>
          <h3 class="margT40">Third period</h3>
          <div class="boxscore-event-ctn"><img style="width:40px;height:40px;float:left;"src="https://cdn.wssmedias.com/websimhockey/logos/LHSVL/SanDiego.jpg"> 
            <h4>13:33 J. BOLL (Trop de joueurs sur la glace - banc)</h4>
            <div class="flowfix"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="boxscore-event-ctn"><img style="width:40px;height:40px;float:left;"src="https://cdn.wssmedias.com/websimhockey/logos/LHSVL/SanDiego.jpg">  
            <h4>06:36 B. BURNS (Avoir accroché)</h4>
            <div class="flowfix"></div>
          </div>
          <h3 class="margT40">Overtime</h3><span>No penalty</span></div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Update the question with the relevant HTML please

Comment: @DebanjanB Can you be more specific? The [...] represents the same xpath segment for every item, if that's what you're referring to. The number and distribution of penalties is different for every game, though.

Comment: @DebanjanB I have added what I think is the relevant HTML. Please let me know if it is or not. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer shows how to get information between 2 known elements using XPath.
Please note that XPath 1.0 is implemented by many languages so the shown results are based on the xpath expression and not the language or utility (`xmllint` in this case).

### Get the count of penalties on second period

#### XPath

All in a single line
`count(//div[@id="tabcontent102"]//div[@class="boxscore-event-ctn" and ./preceding-sibling::h3[.="Second period"] and not(./preceding-sibling::h3[.="Third period"])]/h4)`

Test with `xmllint`

```
xmllint --html --xpath 'count(//div[@id="tabcontent102"]//div[@class="boxscore-event-ctn" and ./preceding-sibling::h3[.="Second period"] and not(./preceding-sibling::h3[.="Third period"])]/h4)' test.html ; echo
```

Result:

```
3
```

To get the third period, change the test values in the predicates
`count(//div[@id="tabcontent102"]//div[@class="boxscore-event-ctn" and ./preceding-sibling::h3[.="Third period"] and not(./preceding-sibling::h3[.="Overtime"])]/h4)`

### Using element position instead of value

#### Xpath

`//div[@id="tabcontent102"]//div[@class="boxscore-event-ctn" and ./preceding-sibling::h3[3] and not(./preceding-sibling::h3[4])]/h4/text()`

Getting `h4` text value on command line

```
(echo 'cat //div[@id="tabcontent102"]//div[@class="boxscore-event-ctn" and ./preceding-sibling::h3[3] and not(./preceding-sibling::h3[4])]/h4/text()') | xmllint --html --shell test.html
```

Result:

```
/ > cat //div[@id="tabcontent102"]//div[@class="boxscore-event-ctn" and ./preceding-sibling::h3[3] and not(./preceding-sibling::h3[4])]/h4/text()
 -------
13:33 J. BOLL (Trop de joueurs sur la glace - banc)
 -------
06:36 B. BURNS (Avoir accroch&Atilde;&copy;)
```

### Get count on last element

#### Xpath

`count(//div[@id="tabcontent102"]//h3[.="Overtime"]/following-sibling::div[@class="boxscore-event-ctn"])`

Using `h3` position
`count(//div[@id="tabcontent102"]//h3[4]/following-sibling::div[@class="boxscore-event-ctn"])`